# onChange of Drop down semantic-ui not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui, react-props

I am working on a react app where I have a dropdown with 3-4 values but when I try to change it,I am only able to access the value part of the options not the text parts.

Here's my form component:

```
<Form.Select
              name='acknowledgementStatus'
              value={this.props.acknowledgementStatusName} //"" initially 
              onChange={this.handleAcknowledgmentStatusChange}
              label='Acknowledgement Status'
              options={[
                {
                  text: 'ACCEPTED',
                  value: 'AA',
                },
                {
                  text: 'REJECTED',
                  value: 'AR',
                },
              ]}
              selectOnBlur={false}
              selectOnNavigation={false}
              icon={
                <StyledDropdownIcon iconName={DownCheveron} iconSize='15' className='dropdown' />
              }
            />
```

Its options has 2 parts,`text` and `value`.The text is whats visible in the dropdown but the value is the id I assign to fetch data from API.

But the text part is not able to change.
Here's the onChange function:

```
handleAcknowledgmentStatusChange = (e, data) => {
    console.log(data.value);
    console.log(data.text);
    this.props.setAcknowledgeStatus(data.value, data.text);
  };
```

The console.log of above change functions prints this:

```
AR
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `value` are unique, you can get the value of `text` from `data.options`:

```
const { text } = data.options.find(option => option.value === data.value);
```

Hopefully that helps!